# Woocommerce : how to Disable "Free shipping" if Coupon applied?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce plugin for online shop.

I set free shipping option after certain amount of order.

how to disable "free shipping" option if coupon applied?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick google lookup.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', function( $packages ) {
    $applied_coupons = WC()->session->get( 'applied_coupons', array() );
    if ( ! empty( $applied_coupons ) ) {
        $free_shipping_id = 'free_shipping:2';
        unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $free_shipping_id ]);
    }
    return $packages;
} );
```

Where $free_shipping_id is set to the id of your free shipping method.